# Proof of onto under interval $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

How do I prove that the function $$f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ defined by:

$$f(x) = \frac{-2x+1}{(2x-1)^2-1}$$

is onto?

Answer (score 2):

Just check that$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-\infty\text{ and that }\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=+\infty.$$Now, the fact that the restricton of $f$ to $(0,1)$ is onto is a consequenc of the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: How would I go about finishing the proof with this info? Why does the intermediate value theorem tell us this is onto? I have never seen onto proven in this manner, so I don't have a frame of reference.

Comment: Take $y\in\mathbb R$. Since $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=+\infty$, there is a $b\in(0,1)$ such that $f(b)\geqslant y$ and since $\lim_{x\to0+}f(x)=-\infty$, there is a $a\in(0,1)$ such that $f(a)\leqslant y$. So, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)=-\infty$
- $\lim_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=\infty$

therefore since $f(x)$ is continuous for $x\in(0,1)$ by IVT we have that $f(x)$ is onto.

Moreover note that for $x\in(0,1)$ we have that $f(x)$

$$f'(x)=\frac{2x^2-2x+1}{x(x-1)^2x^2}\ge 0$$

therefore it is strictly increasing and also one to one on that interval.

Therefore $f(x):(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ is also bijective and invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, set $t = 2x-1$ and for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we show we can find a number $t$ and then an $x \in (0,1)$ such that$f(x) = r$. We have: $\dfrac{t}{1-t^2}=r$. So this gives $t = r - rt^2\implies rt^2+t -r = 0$. If $r = 0 \implies t = 0\implies x = \dfrac{1}{2}$. If $r \neq 0$, $t = \dfrac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}$. If $r > 0$, take $t = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}>0$, and $t = \dfrac{2r}{1+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}< \dfrac{2r}{\sqrt{1+4r^2}}<1\implies t \in (0,1)\implies x = \dfrac{t+1}{2} > \dfrac{1}{2} > 0$, and $x < \dfrac{1+1}{2} = 1\implies x \in (0,1)$. If $r < 0$, choose $t = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}\implies x = \dfrac{-1+2r+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{4r}$. Observe that with $r < 0\implies \sqrt{1+4r^2} < 1-2r$ ( clear ),and this yields $-1+2r+\sqrt{1+4r^2} < 0\implies x > 0$. To complete the proof, you show $x < 1$. But $x = \dfrac{1-2r-\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{-4r}< 1 \iff 1-2r-\sqrt{1+4r^2} < -4r\iff 1+2r < \sqrt{1+4r^2}\iff 4r < 0$, and this is true since $r < 0$ ( by assumption ) .